# How to pass a Environment Pointer to Windows CreateProcess in Java (using jna)

Tags: java, jna, msdn, createprocess

I am calling `Kernel32.Instance.CreateProcess` to start a detached process. One issue I am facing is attempting to pass a environment block to `CreateProcess` each time I do the process does not start.

I first used

```
Advapi32Util.getEnvironmentBlock(environment)
```

to create the block, then to make a Pointer (needed by `CreateProcess`( I used:

```
public static Pointer asPointer(String string) {
    byte[] data;
    try {
        data = Native.toByteArray(string, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Pointer pointer = new Memory(data.length + 1);
    pointer.write(0, data, 0, data.length);
    pointer.setByte(data.length, (byte) 0);
    return pointer;
}
```

That I think results in the double null needed at the end. I did actually set CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT so I tried add two extra nulls to the end of the `Memory`. That still resulted in `CreateProcess` returning false and not starting the command.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Should I be checking a log file that might hint at the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Ah So it seems while using `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` it needs to take `UTF-16LE` `byte[]`. Ensure that each `key=value` is followed by two nulls aka `(byte) 0)`. Finally add two more null bytes. The pointer can be made as above.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502023/how-to-start-a-command-in-windows-under-java-that-is-completely-detached/50522759#50522759